# Почему существует Qt?

Tags: qt, кроссплатформенность, qt-faq

Уже давно существуют виртуальные машины (платформы) вроде Java или того же .NET, которые поддерживают достаточно большое количество аппаратных архитектур, и имеют реализации на самых различных исполняемых средах (включая Embedded).

Почему же тогда появляются программные продукты вроде того же QT, в которые вбухивается куча труда и денег, просто чтобы заставить запускаться программы на разных платформах?

В чем сенс?

Немного информации к размышлению - [Why aren't more desktop apps written with Qt? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88685/why-arent-more-desktop-apps-written-with-qt)

Comment: > В чем сенс? 

в чем что, простите?

Comment: сенс = смысл

[У житті повинен бути сенс.](http://www.zaz.ua/models/sens-sd/tech.html)

Comment: это по-каковски, стесняюсь спросить? По-украински, надо полагать?

Comment: Да, по украински

Comment: Вопрос надо поставить по-другому: зачем вообще нужны низкоуровневые языки типа С, С++, Fortran, D и т.п.

Comment: такие вопросы, по моему скромному мнению, имеет смысл ставить в двух случаях - либо если имеется огромный опыт в разработке на этих языках, а отсюда - доскональное понимание всех их особенностей, достоинств и недостатков и прочих подводных граблей (и, вполне возможно, разочарованиев данных языках), либо если спрашивающий - php-школьник, которому не даются эти чертовы указатели, и который искренне недоумевает, как на этом гадком С++ можно писать

Comment: В первом случае такие вопросы не встают, потому что в таком случае человеку абсолютно ясно, зачем нужны разные языки. Во втором случае школьнику стоит смиренно заткнуться, слушать бородатых матерых дядек и долбить указатели, пока не наступит миг просветления.

Comment: php-школьник - это такой зоологический вид, который в силу каких-то древних мутаций обладает геном, отвечающим за "я самый крутой кулхацкер, написавший аж целый сайт-визитку на <г*но_CMS_name> и если я ничего не понимаю в вашем <language_name> то этот ваш <language_name> - полное г*но"...А если уж php-школьник имел несчастье учиться по каким-нибудь видеокурсам Евгения Попова, неизгладимо повлиявшим на неокрепшую детскую психику этого php-школьника, то тут уж не то что бородатые матерые  дядьки не помогут, тут скорее всего даже хирургическое вмешательство и лоботомия бессильны

Comment: @mikillskegg

         зачем вообще нужны низкоуровневые языки типа С, С++, Fortran, D и т.п.

... java, c#... (у них уровень ненамного выше, особенно java)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Qt был и есть и скорее всего будет, потому что еще есть такие странные люди, которые пишут программы на С++ (представляете себе! и это в 21 веке!) и пишут не без успеха. В том числе и программы с GUI. А Qt делает это и еще много других манипуляций с С++ просто удовольствием. Кроме того, как было замечено, он очень удачно дополняет стандартную библиотеку С++. А писать на С++ будут еще очень долго, потому что есть масса задач, где он (и подобные низкоуровневые языки) не заменим ни джвой, ни шарпом.

По поводу VM. На джаве на настоящий момент (насколько я знаю, могу ошибаться) самый прогрессивный стандартный способ создания GUI - Swing. Работа с ней до крайности гемморойная, сама тяжелая, а интерфейсы выглядят динозаврами. Поэтому GUI на ней пишутся еще реже, чем на Qt.

.Net - очень плотно завязана на винду. Хотя есть Mono, но создание GUI на ней под никсы (насколько помню) отличается от винды, поскольку используется GTK+ => пропадает переносимость. Да и под линями на моно программ совсем мало. Не пошло оно там.

Есть масса привязок Qt к разным языкам, самая качественная - к Питону. Но есть и к той же джаве (хотя  и не полная). Так что Qt - это класс.

И еще: не забывайте про KDE !

Comment: Пожалуй лучший ответ по сабжу)

Comment: @SoloMio вы шутите? Где желчь-то? Вполне адекватные (в том числе и в плане уважения лично к вам) ответы. А вы даже спасибо не сказали

Comment: Откровенно говоря, **вся** кроссплатформенная графика для достаточно сложных задач работает так, что "без слез не взглянешь".

Поэтому время от времени будут появляться новые разработки, а Qt и GTK+ и все другое будет жить и пытаться развиваться.

Comment: @avp, на мой взгляд, Qt вызывает меньше всего слез. Даже наоборот. А QML заставляет застыть с открытым ртом.

Answer (score 8):

Qt появился [раньше](http://www.linuxcenter.ru/lib/books/qt3/qt3_4.phtml), чем [появился](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_1.0) .net. Qt - это фреймворк для С++. Программы, написанные на С++ работают быстрее, чем аналоги на java.

.NET - это фреймворк для C#
Qt - это фреймворк для C++

Comment: Qt появился даже раньше GTK !

Answer (score 8):

ну хотя бы потому что это зрелый качественный продукт для кросс-платформенной разработки с обширной документацией, сформировавшимся сообществом. Плюс к тому открытый код, широкие возможности для разработки визуальных интерфейсов, ну и бесплатность опять же. .NET в отличие от сабжа - не кроссплатформенный продут, да и появился лет на пять позже Qt, как было справедливо замечено выше. Кроме того нужно учитывать, что в отличие от Java и C#, чьи стандартные библиотеки имеют широчайшие наборы классов на все случаи жизни, С++ этим похвастаться не может, что не без успеха способен исправить Qt.

З.Ы. Вероятно, сам факт его существования доставляет вам какие-то неудобства?

Comment: Мне вообще как-то фиолетово, если честно. Просто не понимаю зачем Nokia решила потратить кучу денег на разработку собственной, проприетарной коммерческой версии Qt, когда есть .Net, Mono, JVM, и куча других вкусностей.

Comment: Потому что виртуальные машины - тоже не панацея. Есть масса задач, где они непригодны. 

Конкретно про нокию. Насколько помню, Simbian был построен на Qt. Потом, Qt был разработан  фирмой Trolltech задолго до того, как Нокия купила их биснес. И коммерческая версия имелась с самого начала. 

Кроме того, многие фирмы поддерживают убыточные, но важные для общества проекты. Та же Java была разработана Sun. Много она на джаве заработала?

Answer (score 5):

Я бы помимо всего еще не забывал, что программирование как таковое существует дольше чем java с C#, а значит на более старых языках уже скопилось очень много наработок (алгоритмов, бизнеслогики, да и просто готовых программ), которые в случае перехода массово на более новые языки придется либо выкидывать и переписывать с нуля, либо делать какую-то прослойку, которая тоже будет дополнительно замедлять работу и вносить свою специфику.